# how to remove html element's style attribute using Hpricot?

Tags: html, ruby, hpricot

like this:

```
<p style="font-size: 12pt;">
  Hello world
  <span style="font-weight: bold;">just do it</span>
</p>
```

I want to remove every element's "style" attribute. I want the result like this:

```
<p>Hello world <span>just do it</span></p>
```

how to do this using hpricot?

thanks.

---

ok I have solved this like below:

```
doc = Hpricot("<p style='xxx'>are you ok?</p>")

doc.search("[@style]").each do |e|
  e.remove_attribute("style")
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes writing to stack overflow automatically solves your problems :) (my experience shows that to me)